# Handling form erros under ngrx & ngrx/effects

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-effects, ngrx-store-4.0

I'm trying to design an auth mechanism under ngrx but I've yet to wrap my head around ngrx.

The authentication works like this: client inputs his email and password, a request to /api/auth is made with his credentials, if the credentials aren't correct we receive an error and an error message is seen on the login form. If the credentials are correct we receive the user object and we redirect the user to the home page.

Here is how I see it

[image]

So the part I'm struggling with is the when `@Effect` receives the response.

I assume that in my store I have an `userReducer` that contains the state of the user. When the response from `api/auth` is the user then an action `SET_USER` is dispatched to the reducer to set the user. However I'm not sure what to do with the error message.

- Do I need to have a reducer for the form as well ?
- Do I need a reducer for each form ? Seems to me error message isn't part of the long lived state of an app. It's just something that should be displayed then forgotten.
- How do I redirect on login success ?

Comment: Have you looked at the auth setup at https://github.com/ngrx/platform/tree/master/example-app/app/auth ? this example app shows a pretty good structure for handling errors, and also redirecting on login success using an effect

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.catch` in your effect returning an action like LOGIN_FAILED that handles this scenario. You should definitely have a reducer handling this scenario as opposed to handling it in the reducer for SET_USER.

*Do I need a reducer for each form?*

No. If you design your state smart, you can let the same reducer handle several error messages. However, the returned error message should be set to state, so you probably should have an action+reducer for clearing the error message.

*How do I redirect on login success?*

Disclaimer: I have no experience with this particular scenario.

Since the @ngrx/effects handles side effects (since reducers are pure), it might be possible to let the effect do the redirect.
I am not sure if this is the correct approach, but I would argue that a redirect is a side effect, thus *could* be handled in the effect.

Another option is to use a guard to handle the redirect based on the outcome of the authentication.